# Figures in compiled pdf from latext are not aligned

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment

I have a latex file, and after compiling, the pdf looks as you see. The figures are just jumping around, sometimes over the text, and sometimes aligned to right.
To compile, I do the following:

```
latex 1.tex
dvipdfmx 1.dvi
evince 1.pdf
```

The original file, 1.tex has the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

    \chapter{Daa}  

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[h]

\centering

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{/home/proj/paper/2012/120510_3wayANOVA/ANOVA-3/figures/three_plots.eps}}

\caption{C}
\label{x.eps}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

screenshot looks like this:
[image]

The figure can be downloaded [here](https://expirebox.com/download/b6ba7c660141af6f4fba1cc205bb0bcb.html)

Comment: Do not use `\centerline` in latex but it looks as if the bounding box in your EPS files are incorrect. use `\fbox{\includegraphics....}` to debug and see if the space comes inside or outside the box from`\fbox`

Comment: you could edit the eps files to fix the `%%BoundingBox` comment or use a tool such as ps2eps to add a better one, or supply a fixed bounding box using `bb= a b c d ` in `graphicx` where the numbers a,b are the lower left coordinate and c,d are the upper right coordinate when the postscript is printed directly on a page

Comment: basically that would be a bug in whatever software made the eps files. The BoundingBox comment is not supposed to be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. Sorry for this question, it means that I should add the package graphicx, and then see bb = a b c d in the \includegraphics, right?

Comment: you presumably have graphicx loaded already (but you have not shown any code) so have to guess, but then yes you could add a correct bounding box using bb=... also you have not said how you are processing this file pdflatex can not directly read eps files, are you using latex and dvips, or using pdflatex with the automatic epstopdf conversion package or???

Comment: how can I find a reasonbale value for a b c and d?

Comment: `dvipdfm` or `dvipdfmx` ? but really you should show an example, what options to you use to graphicx package? normally latex defaults to dvips syntax.

Comment: The point is, it is a chapter in my thesis. In diss.tex I use \usepackage{graphicx}, then I include the chapter in diss.tex

Comment: It is how I compile: latex diss
bibtex diss
latex diss
latex diss
latex diss

dvipdfm diss.dvi
evince diss.pdf

Comment: so almost certainly it is defaulting to dvips so it is lucky that the images include at all, try `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}` and use dvipdfmx to convert the dvi file

Comment: It was possible the bounding box was right but failing because you were using the wrong driver but if it is still bad perhaps they really are wrong,  you could deleet the BoundingBox lime the use ps2eps to generate a new one, or print the eps on paper and measure the lower left and upper right coordinates in 1/72 in or ...

Comment: I originally assumed that the bounding boxes in your images are incorrect but if you are using a different graphicx driver option than the driver you are using, then anything is possible, impossible to say as you have not shown any code to reproduce the problem or log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I simplify the example and edit it to match the supplied eps file name

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

    \chapter{Daa}  

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[h]

\centering

\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5, bb=0 0 705 389]{three_plots.eps}}

\caption{C}
\label{x.eps}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

Because the bounding box specified in the `bb` key is incorrect so latex can not position the image correctly.

As far as I can see, the bounding box in the file is correct but

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{three_plots.eps}}
```

produces

Overfull \hbox (117.67122pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--14

as the image is too big so changing that to

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{three_plots.eps}}
```

produces

[image]

with the image centred.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

    \chapter{Daa}  

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[h]

\centering

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{/home/proj/paper/2012/120510_3wayANOVA/ANOVA-3/figures/three_plots.eps}}

\caption{C}
\label{x.eps}
\end{figure}


\end{document}

Comment: Thanks David for your answer. Above code, gives me still unaligned figure. I updated my question with the new code and screenshot.

Comment: perhaps you need to update your tex macros (I used an up to date texlive 2017) (you should not need to put a full path to the image)

Comment: Yes you were right David. I updated the texlive and now it is normal. thanks again for your time.